# How to print a sector?

Tags: java, for-loop, math, console

I want to create a program to print a sector pattern:

```
public class MySector{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<32;j++){
                if((i-16)*(i-16)+(j-16)*(j-16)<16*16){
                    if((i-16)<(j-16)*Math.tan(Math.PI/6)){
                        System.out.print("[]");
                    }else{
                        System.out.print("  ");
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to print a 30 degree sector, at the line

```
(i-16)<(j-16)*Math.tan(Math.PI/6)
```

it is just simplifying atan((i-16)/(j-16)) < Math.PI/6 , however the program seems not print a sector with 30 degrees, instead it prints:

```
                  [][][][][][][][][][][]                    
              [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]                
          [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]            
        [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]          
      [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]        
    [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]      
  [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]    
  [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]    
    [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]  
        [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]  
            [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                  [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                      [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                          [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                              [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                                    [][][][][][][][][][][][]
                                        [][][][][][][][][][]
                                          [][][][][][][][][]
                                              [][][][][][][]
                                                  [][][][]  
                                                      [][]
```

I tried modifying

```
(i-16)<(j-16)*Math.tan(Math.PI/6)
```

as

```
(j-16)<(i-16)*Math.tan(Math.PI/6)
(16-i)<(16-j)*Math.tan(Math.PI/6)
(16-j)<(16-i)*Math.tan(Math.PI/6)
```

but still not print a sector, what is the problem?

Comment: looks like integer rounding error... try `float(i-16)<float(j-16)*Math.tan(Math.PI/6.0)` and if still not OK then you are hiting the 180 degree boundary of `tan` and need to use **sprinter**'s answer with `atan2` or detect sign of `16-i` , `16-j` and add appropriate quadrant corrections

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Math.atan2` instead of `Math.tan`. I tried the following method and it worked perfectly:

```
private boolean inSector(int x, int y) {
    if ((x - 16) * (x - 16) + (y - 16) * (y - 16) > 16 * 16)
        return false;
    double angle = Math.atan(y - 16, x - 16);
    return (angle >= 0 && angle <= Math.PI / 6);
}
```